# Does Magento execute a query to get the review count of each single product on the category listing page?

Tags: magento2, database, review, query, optimization

Let's say that your category page shows 36 products at a time and shows the rating/review count underneath each product title.

Does Magento perform 36 queries to get each of the product's review counts? Or is this all queried once and then stored in a model?

Where can I find the code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento call stack for review entity on category page:

1. #76 vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType);
```

2. #107 vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/ReviewRenderer.php

```
     $this->appendSummaryDataFactory->create()
       ->execute(
           $product,
           $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
           Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE
       );
```

3. #40 vendor/magento/module-review/Model/AppendSummaryData.php

```
/**
     * Append summary data to object filtered by its entity code
     *
     * @param AbstractModel $object
     * @param int $storeId
     * @param string $entityCode
     * @retrun void
     */
    public function execute(AbstractModel $object, int $storeId, string $entityCode): void
    {
        $summaryCollection = $this->summaryCollectionFactory->create();
        $summaryCollection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
        $summaryCollection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ['review_entity' => $summaryCollection->getResource()->getTable('review_entity')],
                'main_table.entity_type = review_entity.entity_id',
                'entity_code'
            )
            ->where('entity_pk_value = ?', $object->getId())
            ->where('entity_code = ?', $entityCode);
        $summaryItem = $summaryCollection->getFirstItem();

        $object->addData(
            [
                'reviews_count' => $summaryItem->getData('reviews_count'),
                'rating_summary' => $summaryItem->getData('rating_summary'),
            ]
        );
    }
```

Based on this call stack Magento get the review on for each product.